Can I grow Nertera Granadensis in a glass bowl?
I was in a garden centre today, and saw a Nertera Granadensis...

I resisted the temptation to buy it until I'd done some research.
It seems that one of the challenges in keeping this as a houseplant (which would be my intent) is keeping the humidity high enough.
I have a spherical glass bowl (something like this one), about 18cm diameter, with an opening of about 11cm. I have some carnivorous plants in my greenhouse, and last spring/summer, I brought a pot containing a Venus fly trap, and various droseras indoors. I put the pot in the bowl, added clay balls to about half way up the pot, and kept it topped up with water to just below the top of the clay balls. This kept the humidity inside the bowl up, but with enough open space at the top to allow fresh air in. The plants did really well in there, enabling me to enjoy them indoors. At the end of the autumn, I put the pot back in the greenhouse for the winter to go dormant.
I was wondering if I could grow a Nertera Granadensis in the bowl. If I did the same, it would keep the humidity up. Unlike the carnivorous plants, I guess I would need to keep it in there all year round. Given that these plants have shallow roots, I would hope that having the pot sit in water wouldn't be a problem, as the soil above the water level shouldn't be too soggy.
The light and temperature requirements wouldn't be too hard for me to achieve, it's only the humidity that concerns me.
Does this sound practical? I really like the plant, but don't want to get one unless I have a good chance of keeping it healthy.

The bowl idea sounds good to me. Just keep that up year-round and you should be good (also, it's amazing how closely this stuff minus the berries resembles Soleirolia while being completely unrelated)

Thanks for the reply. Will it be a problem if the pot always has the bottom half under water? This should be well below the roots, but would the amount of water that seeps up be enough to be a problem? Thanks again

No, it shouldn't be a problem.
